# Calculate depth for light intensity

Tags: logarithms

I'm totally stumped with this one. Don't know where to start. Any hint is appreciated.

For every meter a diver descends below the water surface, the light intensity is reduced by 3.5%. At what depth is the light intensity only 25% of that at the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if we are $1$ meter below the water, the intensity of light is $1-0.035=0.965$ the intensity at the surface.

If we submerge another meter, the intensity is  $0.965\times 0.965=(0.965)^2$.

Continuing, if we are $x$ meters below the surface, the intensity is $(0.965)^x$.

We need to find $x$ such that $(0.965)^x=0.25$.

Proceeding, we find that at

$$x=\frac{\log(0.25)}{\log(0.965)}$$

the intensity is 25%.

Answer (score 0):

As the diver goes 1 m.. It reduces by $1-0.035$ and similarly.. After 2 m, it is $(1-0.035) (1-0.035)$ So,we have to solve this equation after $x$ m... $$(1-0.035)^x=0.25$$ Solving gives using logarithms $$x\approx38.9111474113$$